# Differentiate under integral sign for Principal Value of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}dx$

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

The following result is well known and is interpreted as a Cauchy Principal Value

$$ P.V. \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}dx=\pi \cot \left(a \pi\right)  \qquad \text{for}\,\,a \in \left(0,1\right) $$

My question is, once it's established , may I bring inside the integral the differential operator to get the result without having to justify it (in the sense of the Principal Value)?

$$ \frac{d}{da}\left( P.V. \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}dx=\pi \cot \left(a \pi\right)\right)$$

$$  P.V. \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1} \ln x}{1-x}dx=-\pi^2 \csc^2 \left(a \pi\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid the subtlety of the Principal Value by considering the corresponding converging integral

$$ I(a)=\frac12 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}-x^{-a}}{1-x}dx=\pi \cot \left(a \pi\right)  
$$
and evaluate the following integral by performing normal differentiation under the integral sign

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1} \ln x}{1-x}dx=I’(a) = -\pi^2 \csc^2 \left(a \pi\right)
$$

Comment: Shouldn´t your integral be $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{a-1}-x^{-a}}{1-x}dx$$?

Comment: Additionally, how do you proof that the these two are the "same"  avoiding the Principal Value?

Comment: @Ricardo770 - the integral over $(1, \infty)$ is the same in value

Comment: what are the restriction on $a$ for the integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}-x^{-a}}{1-x}dx$ to be convergent? The numerator should vanish faster than the denominator in the $\lim_{x \longrightarrow 1}$, right?

Comment: @Ricardo770 - the range of convergence $a\in(0,1)$